# HTML Command Prompt Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, command, prompt

I'm interested in making a command prompt style navigation tool for my website. I was looking into the JQuery Terminal Plugin but most of the information is just going over my head. I simply want a blinking cursor to appear with some instructions. The user can then type such things as: Home, Contact Us, About, etc, and be taken to the respective page.

An example of this would be http://ohmycode.fr/

Instead of having many commands, I just want to type Home and it will take me to my main page. Contact Us and it will take me to my contact page, etc.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<form id="command-prompt">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#command-prompt input[type='submit']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = $("#command-prompt input[type='text']").val();
    window.location.pathname = "/" + value + ".html";
});
```

For exemple if you try typing about in input and click Go you will go to www.yourdomain.com/about.html

Answer (score 0):

i made this fiddle for you:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/v3yVf/3/)

just hide the input borders by css (and use more css to style it if you want to):

```
input#my_console {
    border: 0;
}
input#my_console:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

use focus on the input to make the cursor blink:

```
$("#my_console").focus();
```

use the jQuery `keyup` event to check if the return key was used in your input field. return key's `keyCode` is "13". then compare the value of the input field to your required keywords. use `window.location` if the typed-in text matches a keyword to forward the user to another page. if it doesn't match any of your keywords, output some error message.

```
$("#my_console").on("keyup", function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var my_input = $("#my_console").val();

    if (code == 13) {
        if (my_input == "home") {
            window.location = "index.html";
        } else if (my_input == "contact") {
            window.location = "contact.html";
        }else{
            $("#my_console").val("unknown keyword");
            $("#my_console").select();
        }
    }
});
```